# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'has_header'

Tags: python, django, dictionary

This is my code in my template file

```
{% load section_settings %} ## Loading a template tags
{% section_settings declaration.id user.id as the_section_setting %}
```

Now the value of :

```
the_section_setting = {'A': {'included': True, 'editable': True, 'alwaysIncluded': False, 'complete':False}, 'C': {'included': False, 'editable': True, 'alwaysIncluded': False, 'complete': False}}
```

Now in my template file when I tried to run this code in an js script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initTree(showline){    
    {% for section in the_section_setting %}    
    alert("{{ the_section_setting[section]['included'] }}")
    {% endfor %}
        }   
</script>
```

This throws error `'tuple' object has no attribute 'has_header'` . Basically I have tested the same in python shell , it is working fine for me. But not in the template. What is mistake I am doing. I wanted the value of `included` key for each element in the dict.
Thanks in Advance .

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError at /declaration/2991/detail

'tuple' object has no attribute 'has_header'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://10.6.208.12:8000/declaration/2991/detail
Django Version:     1.4
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'tuple' object has no attribute 'has_header'

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/cache.py in patch_vary_headers, line 140
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.6
```

Comment: why not post your Traceback here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax would be

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initTree(showline)
        {    
           {% for section, secval in the_section_setting.iteritems %}
           alert("{{secval.included}}")
           {% endfor %}
        }   
</script>
```

To be more verbose, I would go for something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initTree(showline)
        {    
           {% for section, secval in the_section_setting.iteritems %}
               {% if secval.include %}
                   alert("The {{ section }} is included.")
               {% else %}
                   alert(""The {{ section }} is not included.")
               {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
        }   
</script>
```

Help docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/

Comment: I have tried this `alert({{ section.'included' }})` but still the same error

Comment: I already tried this , it is showing no error . But the alert message is blank , not True or False which it should be .

Comment: If I do `alert({{ section }})` then I am getting the values like `A` , `C` . Which is fine. But not the value of `included` key .

Comment: Somewhere you're returning a tuple instead of a response object. That's why you're getting that error. 

Furthermore, you shouldn't mix and match javascript